# xvfb-run: line 171: kill: (25939) - No such process

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, xvfb

All automated test runs successfully. but xvfb issue causes the build failure in Jenkins.

I have used below commnad in ExecuteShell option available under Jenkins to run my test cases on headless browser

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin/mvn clean test -Dbrowser=firefox
```

Getting the below output:

```
Results :

Tests run: 22, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] Total time: 10:19 min

[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/47M


/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 171: kill: (25939) - No such process

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

As we can see in the output  `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS`.
But `/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 171: kill: (25939) - No such process` causes the builld failure.

Could anybody please provide some workaround for this?

Comment: What is line 171 of `xvfb-run`? Is the script online somewhere it can be seen?

Comment: xvfb-run is running a bunch of code. Dont know which line it taking as 171.

Comment: Does it look roughly like [this](https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!xorg-x11-server/70130e98ab8c06ce3f7e7d65a80e71aa5f09f614/SOURCES!xvfb-run.sh;jsessionid=o6zzn1bogxm4iee8l4ugs6q1)? The problem is that, for some reason, Xvfb has already died by the time the script tries to kill it and so `kill` fails. I don't know why that would be. You could modify the script to handle that case but it clearly doesn't think that's something that should generally happen.

Comment: Add "-e /tmp/xvfb.log" to get a log from xvfb.  This might help isolate the problem.

Comment: I have this same issue interacting with wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I have the same problem with bamboo and slimerjs

Answer (score 14):

I had this same problem when trying to run `wkhtmltopdf` thru `xvfb-run`.

In my PHP script, I executed `/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf ...` several times in the same script. The first one always worked, but the second one failed consistently with the same error you posted about.

Adding `-e /tmp/xvfb.log` to the second command revealed this in the log:

> Fatal server error: (EE) Server is already active for display 99  If
>   this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X99-lock   and start
>   again.

The solution in my case was to add the `-a` flag to the command:

`/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf ...`

Which will tell xvfb-run to "try to get a free server number, starting at --server-num".

Comment: thanks @brian , just for comment ..  now that option seems deprecated, the new one is option -d / --auto-display

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. What does it change? Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

I could skip the same error using a little trick:

```
sleep(10);
```

on my code... after ends a task and slept my PHP code I could run another task without any errors... following my PHP script...

hope it helps